# how do I know where my application comes from?

Tags: android, google-play, package-managers

I need your help. I have two questions !

1) How can I know where an application I download comes from? Google Play or others.

I use something like that to get some informations about installed packages; but I didn't found the way to get where a package come from ! http://myandroidStore.com/myNewGame.apk for exemple.

```
List<PackageInfo> packages = getActivity() .getPackageManager()
                       .getInstalledPackages(0);

for (int i=0; i<packages.size(); i++) {     
PackageInfo packageInfo = packages.get(i);
AppList tmpList = new AppList();
tmpList.applicationName = packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getActivity()
                .getPackageManager()).toString();

tmpList.packageName = packageInfo.packageName; 
tmpList.versionName = packageInfo.versionName; 
tmpList.versionCode = packageInfo.versionCode; 

tmpList.provider = packageInfo.providers;
tmpList.firstInstallTime = packageInfo.firstInstallTime;
tmpList.lastUpdateTime = packageInfo.lastUpdateTime;
tmpList.signatures = packageInfo.signatures;
}
```

2) When "Unknown Sources" isn't selected I can't download application beyond Google Play.
Do you have an idea how Android check this verification?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) How can I know where an application I download comes from? Google Play or others.

AFAIK the system provides no means for you to get this information. If you are interested in obtaining it you'd have to make seperate apk files with something unique embedded in them, that way you'd know based on that unique string where the apk came from at runtime.

> 2) When "Unknown Sources" isn't selected I can't download application beyond Google Play. Do you have an idea how Android check this verification?

I assume that the PackageManager is what is making the check for this. Not certain though.